# how to import .sql file UTF-8 in mysql databse with php

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

Problem when importing database UTF-8 encoded file table
Arabic language change within the table
**How can I import the table encodes UTF-8**
This is the current code I want to modify it

```
    $sqlFile = 'sql/plugins.sql';
    $queries = file_get_contents($sqlFile);
    $queries = explode(';', $queries);

    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        mysql_query($query);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PHP.  (And, when using PHP, do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` interface.)

Probably all you need is the commandline tool:

```
mysql < sql/plugins.sql
```

Comment: How can I have been add it database automatically call in the php file

Comment: Another approach is to use `LOAD DATE INFILE ...` from PHP.  Be sure to include the `CHARACTER SET utf8` clause.